# access cookies in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cookies

How can I access cookies my browser stored? I am using Chrome.

[image]

This is the cookies panel in the `Settings->Privacy->Content Settings->All cookies and site data`. Is there a way to access these files manually and edit them?

Comment: Search for "chrome edit cookies" - you will find several extensions that allow editing of cookies.

Comment: I can right click and inspect them